# Convert NSData Response in Array

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray, nsdata

I call a WS and I receive the response `NSData`.
   I print the reuqest :

```
   data = <66096669 6c65312e 7478740a 66096669 6c65322e 7478740a 66096162 632e7478 740a4609 666f6c64 6572310a 4609666f 6c646572 320a6609 66696c65 332e7478 740a6609 66696c65 342e7478 740a4609 666f6c64 657233>
```

I convert the response to NSString :

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"newStr = %@",newStr);
```

When I print the newStr :

```
newStr =
f   file1.txt
f   file2.txt
f   abc.txt
F   folder1
F   folder2
f   file3.txt
f   file4.txt
F   folder3
```

I need to populate a `UITableView` with the content from NSString and I need to add the string content intro a `NSSArray`.

Comment: If you review the documentation for NSString your question will be answered.

Comment: Thanks for information ! I fix the problem using  self.dataSourceArray = [newStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert **NSData response to Array** like this

```
    NSError* error;
    if (responseData != nil){
    NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",json);

  }
```